# Datepicker UI src from jQuery does not work, but src from Google does. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to use a jQuery datepicker:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Interestingly, I copy and paste the source code into an .html file and open it up in Chrome. The datepicker does not work. Here is the source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

However, I change the source of the scripts and css from jQuery to Google and it suddenly works.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm happy to see it work, but I do not understand why. This is especially confusing as I imagine the src directly from jQuery, the source of this code, should be more reliable than the one provided by Google, correct?

Comment: You have to use a webserver, something like WAMP or EasyPHP, otherwise `//` won't work as a protocol.

Comment: I just copied your exactly code, it works in chrome. Which browser you are using?

Comment: Just added http: in front of the // and it works! Feel free to add that as an answer so I can close the question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well, did you copy and paste it directly? I realized my code does not work unless I add "http:" in front of the //

Comment: I copied your second code which contains http. of course you have to add it when i get the code, example, from jsfiddle site.

Comment: The second code always worked, but I needed to add the "http:" to the first code to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add http: In front of the //

// won't work on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why i.e. the block:

> script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">

will work in the jQueryUI page is because they are referencing a local file for them (this file exists in their servers).

When you try to use the date picker on your browser, you will have to reference jQuery from an external source (like googleapis or jquery.com). As CMadi says, putting http: in front of the // will work for you.

Another solution would be to download all the .js and .css that you reference and put them next to the .html file that you have.